# Уменьшается объем жесткого диска до нуля

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rar

У меня SSD 250 ГБ с установленной Ubuntu.

Пытаюсь распаковать rar файл. Я просто делаю двойной щелчок по архиву. После, я переношу любой файл из окна архива в свой каталог (это может быть даже текстовый файл = 1кб).

Я вижу бесконечный прогрессбар и замечаю, какой объем памяти SSD постепенно уменьшается до нуля и не возвращается.

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, что происходит? А как восстановить потерянную память?

Решение:

С помощью ncdu выяснил, что в корзине лежит 60Гб. Хотя я туда ничего не помещал, систему тольк оустановил. Очистил корзину и память вернулась!!!

Дря корректного извлечения использовал - unrar x backup.rar

Comment: скорее всего архив в этот момент распаковывается в временный каталог (/tmp). Но свободного места у Вас мало... когда место кончилось, то и распаковывать больше нечего. Что делать? самый простой способ - ребутнуть машину - tmp при этом обычно чиститься.

Comment: @KoVadim я пытаюсь только один файл размером 1кб достать из архива. Места на диске 150Гб. При перетаскивании этого файла объем свободной памяти падает стремительно. Перезагрузка не помогает. Память как упала на свободном месте, так и остается.

Comment: Берите инструменты для анализа занятого места (вроде ncdu/kdirstat/baobab) и смотрите где место занялось

Comment: Возможно, местный "проводник" открывает архив какой-то универсальной тулзой, которая не умеет "вытащить один файл" и эмулирует это через "распаковать-скопировать-удалить". Попробуйте воспользоваться rar архиватором из командной строки.

Comment: @ks_on_v если архив "іsolid", а Вы пытаетесь вытащить самый последний файл, то обычно архиватор вынужден распаковать все.

Comment: @KoVadim да там содержимого не больше 10Гб. А сожрало уже больше 50Гб(

Comment: есть ещё такая штука, как zip-бомба. Когда махонький архив распаковывается в громаднейший файл. Попробуйте другой просмотрщик.

Comment: @KoVadim с помощью ncdu выяснил, что в корзине лежит 60Гб. Хотя я туда ничего не помещал, систему тольк оустановил. Очистил корзину и память вернулась!!! Попробовал утилитой unzip из консоли разархивировать. Она зяла файлы из всех папок архива и засунула в исходную директорию. Т.е. уничтожила иерархию папок( Очень страно. Могло ли повлиять то, что архив на винде создавался?